# Saving layers with diferent types to a single GPX file

Tags: pyqgis, gps, vector-layer, gpx

I have the following twos methods to save a vector layer in the project folder

The first one is generic and the second calls the first to save specifically a GPX file

In order to export one group of my project that contains the vector that I need (at least two layers of points plus one layer of lines) to GPS receiver, I need to save a GPX file.

But every time the result file contains only the last layer processed. I checked and each layer used create a new GPX and overwrite the previous one.

How can I save all the features in a single GPX on QGIS?

Here comes my code:

````
    def save_vector(self, layer, project, projection, path, first, conteiner):
        context = project.transformContext()
        options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
        options.layerName = layer.name()
        options.fileEncoding = layer.dataProvider().encoding()
        options.driverName = conteiner
        if conteiner == 'GPX':
            options.datasourceOptions = ['GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=ON']
            options.skipAttributeCreation = True
            if layer.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.GeometryType.LineGeometry:
                options.layerOptions = ['FORCE_GPX_TRACK=ON']
        if not first:
            options.ct = QgsCoordinateTransform(layer.crs(), projection, context)
            options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer
        result, error_string = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(layer, path, context, options)```

    def save_GPX(self):
        tree_layers = self.root.findGroup('Vectors').findLayers()
        layers = [vector.layer() for vector in tree_layers]
        path = self.project.absoluteFilePath()[:-4] + '_GPS'
        for layer in layers:
            if not os.path.exists(path):
                self.save_vector(layer, self.project, self.project.crs(),
                                               path, True, "GPX")
            else:
                self.save_vector(layer, self.project, self.project.crs(),
                                               path, True, "GPX")
````